# Why isn't Input.GetMouseButtonDown working to allow me to shoot?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Code in the Update function works when SemiAuto is false, but when it is true, it just doesn't shoot

```
        if (canShoot && !Grapple) { 
            canShoot = false;
            StartCoroutine(ShootTimer());
            if (semiauto && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
                    shoot.Shoot();
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !semiauto){
                shoot.Shoot();
            }
        }
```

I know that shoot.Shoot() works because when semiauto is true it works fine, and that it is in Update not FixedUpdate so that can't be the issue.

Comment: is it in update or fixed update?

Comment: `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` returns `true` only on a single frame (i.e. on only one of `Update()` calls), if it happens that on that frame `canShoot == false` or `!Grapple == false`, then your code never reaches check whether input on this single frame was given

Comment: thanks @AlexLarionov that was very helpful, it made me realize that the lines two and three and in the wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code checks 2 different paths (maybe not on purpose?):

The path that works, per your description, checks:

If `semiauto` is `false` AND `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` is true THEN shoot

.. but the path that doesn't work, checks:

If `semiauto` is `true` AND `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` is true THEN shoot

Notice the difference? One calls `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`, while the other one calls `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`. Since everything else is the same, I suspect the first call returns `true`, while the second one returns `false`, causing your if statement body to not execute.

So, how to fix this? If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, here's the logic, in English:

IF mode is `semiauto`, then shoot once per click; otherwise, shoot as long as the mouse button is held down.

With that in mind, we can introduce a `bool` to know if we are in shooting mode. You have a `canShoot`, but I'm not sure if you're using it for something else. So, somewhere next to your `bool canShoot` (class scope, not functions scope), add: `bool isShooting = false;`

Now, in your update we need to turn shooting mode on and off whenever mouse button is pressed or released:

```cs
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
   // Mouse button is pressed - enter shooting mode
   isShootingMode = true;
}
else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
   // Mouse button released - exit shooting mode
   isShootingMode = false;
}
```

The above code now controls if we're in shooting mode or not. Now for the `semiauto` part, also in `Update`

```cs
if(isShootingMode)
{
   shoot.Shoot(); // we know we're in shooting mode, so shoot!
   if(semiauto)
   {
      // If we're in semi-auto mode, exit shooting mode, as we already shot once
      isShootingMode = false;
   }
}
```

That's it! Just integrate that with the rest of your logic.